# React Router Redux, Appends LocationBeforeTransitions to API Requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, fetch, react-router-redux

I’m currently working on a rails/react/redux project. I recently added react-router-redux "^4.0.8" and react-router "^3.0.2" and now the current LocationBeforeTransitioning is appended to every API request URL (i.e. should be: `http://localhost:3000/api/posts?term=“test”`, but is attempting to fetch `http://localhost:3000/categories/api/posts?term=“test”` in the posts component.

The project is fairly large, but I’ve included some potentially relevant snippets below:

routes.js

```
module.exports = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRedirect to="/categories"/>
    <Route path="/categories" component={Categories}/>
    <Route path="/:category" component={Posts}/>
    <Route path="/categories/posts" component={Posts}/>
    <Route path="/categories/:post" component={Citations}/>
    …
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
  </Route>
)
```

configureStore.js

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  })
  const router = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, router)
  ))
…
```

actions.js

```
…
export function fetchPosts (term = '', random = false) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    fetch(`${API_URL}posts?term=${term}&random=${random}`, {
      method: 'get',
      headers: !sessionStorage.jwt ? default_header : auth_header
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (!json || json.error) {
        let default_error = 'An Error Occured.';
        throw `Oops! ${json.exception || default_error}`;
      }
      dispatch(requestPostSuccess(term, json));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(requestPostError(error));
    });
  }
}
…
```

Posts.js

```
… 
class Posts extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    if (this.props.location.pathname.slice(1).split('/')[0] == 'categories'){
      this.props.actions.fetchPosts('', true)
    }
  }
…
```

Anyone know what might be causing this and/or a workaround?

Comment: happens to me as well, solution was found?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the value of `API_URL` in the fetchPosts function.